# "Can that change be easily made on your side"

Tags: grammar

"Can that change be easily made on your side?" - is this proper grammar? Sounds a little odd to me.

Comment: What precisely sounds odd here?

Comment: Ditto @fev. You need to specify what it is about the sentence that concerns you. I see that "steve" has posted an answer assuming that the problem is the use of the phrase "your side", but is that the issue or is it something else?

Comment: In American English, "on your end" would be idiomatic.

Comment: @TimR "at your end" seems even better. But there are some situations where "side" is the better metaphor.

Comment: @Barmar:  "at your end" is fine, but I've heard **on your end** far more often in situations where people are trying to have two systems mesh, as with a data-exchange between companies. When the data being sent doesn't mesh with the recipient's structure, one of the parties will typically ask, "Can the change be made on *your* end?" *Dude, don't send me a zipcode in Excel in a number column, as that will strip out leading zeroes! Can't you make that change on your end?*

Answer (score 1):

"your side" is referring to the person's ability to make the change where they are.

The use of "side" seems to indicate that there is a separation between the two groups, and one group doesn't have access and is asking whether the other group does.

We can reword the sentence as, "We can't do it here, so can you do it with the tools or help where you are?"